# UIImageView doesn't follow origin.x position

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am trying to add set of imageviews on a UIScrollView. My problem is that the imageviews are overlapping with each other even though I increase the x value. What's also weird is that this problem is only for devices with ios 4.2.1, but works on simulator 4.2 and other device ios.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)addScrollView {

      [self setImages];

      scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
      scrollView.delegate = self;

      [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
      [scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

      scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
      scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
      scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
      scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

      [self addSubview:scrollView];

      NSUInteger nimages;
      CGFloat cx = 0;

      for (nimages = 1; nimages < [imagesArray count] ; nimages++) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:nimages]];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];


        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.origin.x = cx;
        rect.origin.y = 0;
        rect.size.width = 320;
        rect.size.height = 480;

        imageView.frame = rect;

        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];

        [imageView release];

        cx += rect.size.width;

      }

      [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, [scrollView bounds].size.height)];
 }
```

Called from here:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

     if (self) {

            [self addScrollView];

            UIImage *handImg;

            UIImageView *longhand = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            minuteHand = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 55, 320, 480)];

            handImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clock_long_hand.png"];
            longhand.image = handImg;

                    /************** TRY COMMENT OUT HERE **************/

            longhand.frame = CGRectMake(155 - (handImg.size.width / 2), 240 - handImg.size.height, handImg.size.width, handImg.size.height);
                [minuteHand addSubview:longhand];
            [self addSubview:minuteHand];

                    /************** END COMMENT OUT HERE **************/

            [longhand release];
   }
   return self;
}
```

UPDATE:

This code is in a UIView subclass which is why I use [self...] instead of [self.view...].

I tried experimenting and found that when I comment out the indicated parts, the scrollview works fine. But when it is included, this is when the imageviews are overlapped.

I know that the scrollview's content size is correct because its indicator continues to scroll, with just a plain black background.

I am really confused why this works on some ios and not on others. Hope you can help.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what is causing problems but it seems to me that you have a property of your view controller called scrollView (because you use self.scrollView at one point) with a backing iVar also called scrollView. When you initialize scrollView you use the backing iVar and not the property which means that it's not retained. What happens if you try using self.scrollView everywhere that you have scrollView?

Comment: sounds you are trying to make a gellery, why don't you use [existing galleries](https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer)

Comment: @Darren I tried using self.scrollView, it didn't seem to change anything. My images are still overlapping.

Comment: @AdilSoomro Sorry, I would like to try that photoviewer but maybe for my next apps. I want to implement my own first since I also have added functionalities here. Thank you very much though.

Comment: Where are you calling the code in your question? It looks like something that might be called in the viewDidLoad method of a view controller, but you have self.frame and [self addSubview:scrollView]. Is that actually self.view.frame and [self.view addSubview:scrollView] in your code? Also, have you tried setting the opacity of the imageViews to something less than 1 to verify that they are actually underneath the last view? And is your scrollView.contentSize always correct, ie. can you scroll the full width, but are seeing a black background everywhere but the first 320 pixels?

Comment: @Darren Hello again. I updated my code with a few discoveries I found. I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This might have something to do with autoresizing mask. The width actual images, I mean .png files is bigger than 320, right?

Comment: Nope, sorry. My images are exactly 320x480 and 640x960 for retina display.